# Populating string property of Servlet using Spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Here I have some of my code examples

**Servlet Class**

```
private String welcomeNote;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
    context.getBean("SomeServlet");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println(welcomeNote);
}

public void setWelcomeNote(String welcomeNote) {
    this.welcomeNote = welcomeNote;
}
```

**Spring-config.xml**

```
<bean id="SomeServlet" class="SomeServlet">
    <property name="welcomeNote" value="aasomdp" />
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Hello, I can't figure out how to inject `welcomeNote` property inside `servlet` class. When I deploy it and open it up in web browser it's always null, no matter what I do.

I am using plain Spring, not Spring MVC.

I'm learning Spring and web aspects of Java, so I must be missing something important. Thank you all for advice.

Comment: I would recommend to first learn Java Servlets and Spring separately. Both have their special aspects, and putting both together in your excercise programs will only confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
SomeServlet  sv = (SomeServlet)context.getBean("SomeServlet");
sv. setWelcomeNote(welcomeNote);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring you actually don't need any custom servlet. The only servlet you need is DispatcherServlet. Add @Controller annotated classes instead your servlet to process requests